# How to exponentially decay a value along an axis?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a tensor of shape `(sequence_length,batch_size,1)` (which is `(5,5,1)` in the following example). Every sequence has a single entry that I want to exponentially decay along the sequence (for example with a decay factor of `0.99`) for `n` steps (here: `n = 2`).

**Example**:

[image]

Is there an efficient way to realize something like that (either in `PyTorch` or `numpy`).

Edit (visualizing the additive nature):

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the mechanics of the said "decay"? From natural sciences, a process of decay makes some sense for non-zero quantities,that "decay" over time (which might be a continuous dimension,though discrete here,as using n-steps,in which a power-law reflects the process of decay of the initial quantity). Power-series for all quantities,that started being zero in the initial state-tensor,remain zero all the way forwards,won't they?Yet your illustration shows some randomly sprinkling non-zero tensor-elements in places,that started as zeros + process of decay is incoherent in time.Why/How?

Comment: An error in the picture has got me :o) Is the process of (rather) one-side directed, n-steps-deep, axis-aligned transfer-function **additive** for cases, where some non-zero value already exists along the (alike diffusion)-transfer-path, **or max()**-controlled by a higher of the present/diffusion-alike transfer propagated value? Too many undefined properties, yet important for using the **`numpy`**-powers for smart tensor striding and/or vectorisation tricks :o)

Comment: The context is actually reinforcement learning, specifically q-learning, where you have discrete transitions in time. The values are actually rewards for the agent, and in my case, these rewards are given at the end of the sequences, so here, they also mark the end of the episode (hence zeros afterwards). In q-learning the expected reward is learned. In the theoretical framework rewards in the near future are higher weighted than in the far future, that's why the reward decays (and 0.99 is actually the gamma factor).

Comment: n-steps, then, is an extension to speed up the training process. It allows you to take a look into the actual future. For other non-zero values besides the one at the end of the sequence, they simply would add up (something like ``4 + 0.99 * 2 + 0.99^2 * 9``) and would need to be decayed as well.

Comment: I have added an example for that, and updated the original picture :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like convolution to me:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d

# just for printing:
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as nlr
def show(x): print(nlr.unstructured_to_structured(x))

a = "00000","00100","10000","03502","00010"
A = np.array(a).view('U1').reshape(5,5,1).astype(float)

show(A)
# [[(0.,) (0.,) (0.,) (0.,) (0.,)]
#  [(0.,) (0.,) (1.,) (0.,) (0.,)]
#  [(1.,) (0.,) (0.,) (0.,) (0.,)]
#  [(0.,) (3.,) (5.,) (0.,) (2.,)]
#  [(0.,) (0.,) (0.,) (1.,) (0.,)]]

show(convolve1d(A,np.r_[np.logspace(2,0,3,base=0.99),0,0],axis=0,mode="constant"))
# [[(0.9801,) (0.    ,) (0.99  ,) (0.    ,) (0.    ,)]
#  [(0.99  ,) (2.9403,) (5.9005,) (0.    ,) (1.9602,)]
#  [(1.    ,) (2.97  ,) (4.95  ,) (0.9801,) (1.98  ,)]
#  [(0.    ,) (3.    ,) (5.    ,) (0.99  ,) (2.    ,)]
#  [(0.    ,) (0.    ,) (0.    ,) (1.    ,) (0.    ,)]]
```

Comment: That's a simple and elegant idea which solves the problem in a single line! And as a bonus, this can easily be transferred to PyTorch via ``torch.logspace`` and ``torch.nn.functional.conv1d`` as well, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### <sup>Given the last comments,</sup> the **`numpy`**-based problem solution is doable:

While there may be smarter `numpy`-vectorised trics doable, the non-interfering adding of many 1D-"diffusion"-kernels over a **`.view`**-based strided-tricks data seems uncertain ATM not to introduce unwanted side-effects of skewed-superposition(s) of both original plus kernel-added values from re-propagation of superposed values instead of 1D-"diffusion"-kernel propagations of just the original tensor values ( before any kernel-added products get added as these may reach the same tensor-cell location )

---

**- step 0:** create a constant, Q-learning gamma-based "kernel"-vector **`kernel`** and a zeroed-copy of the `ORIGINAL_TENSOR` in `RESULT_TENSOR`

---

```
>>> N_STEPS  = 2
>>> Q_FACTOR = 0.99
>>> kernel = np.ones( N_STEPS )
>>> for i in range( 1, kernel.shape[0] ):
...     kernel[:i] *= Q_FACTOR
... 
>>> kernel
array([0.9801, 0.99  , 1.    ])
>>> RESULT_TENSOR = np.zeros( ORIGINAL_TENSOR.shape )
```

In case of `[SPACE]`-domain related problem, the interim adder storage may keep way smaller, using just a current-column-wise mapping, so as to minimise the overall RAM-footprint.

---

**- step 1:** for each tensor-column, use the `numpy` striding-tricks for forming a 2D-meta-view of each of the such tensor-column, that has depth equal to n-steps ( for reversed-propagated q-rewards ) - like was used in this `rolling_window()` example for 2D-matrix <sub>(needs adapting for using over a vector-column or if going a bit wilder, going here straight across the while original tensor)</sub>:

---

```
def rolling_window( aMatrix, aRollingWindowLENGTH ):                    #
    """                                                                 __doc__
    USAGE:   rolling_window( aMatrix, aRollingWindowLENGTH )

    PARAMS:  aMatrix                a numpy array
             aRollingWindowLENGTH   a LENGTH of a Rolling Window

    RETURNS: a stride_trick'ed numpy array with rolling windows

    THROWS:  n/a

    EXAMPLE: >>> x = np.arange( 10 ).reshape( ( 2, 5 ) )

             >>> rolling_window( x, 3 )
             array([[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]],
                    [[5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]])

             >>> np.mean( rolling_window( x, 3 ), -1 )
             array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
                    [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
    """
    new_shape   = aMatrix.shape[:-1] + ( aMatrix.shape[-1]
                                       - aRollingWindowLENGTH + 1,
                                         aRollingWindowLENGTH
                                         )
    new_strides = aMatrix.strides    + ( aMatrix.strides[-1], )
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided( aMatrix,
                                            shape   = new_shape,
                                            strides = new_strides
                                            )

meta2D = rolling_window( aTensorCOLUMN_to_PROCESS, N_STEPS )
```

---

**- step 2:** for the case of column-wise tensor processing, multiply the `kernel` by a scalar - by each current column's 2D-meta-view matrix "rows'"[-1] value and **`+=` store** such produced "scaled"-kernel into a separate, `RESULT_TENSOR` (or the above explained `[SPACE]`-domain motivated re-useable/re-erased interim column-adder ) accumulating additive results ( IMHO this cannot be in-place, as the kernel-"back-propagated" rewards must not "increase" the other (though additive in result) Q-rewards, not yet processed by the `kernel`, as the strided-tricks are just a view and storing in-place would interfere with the not yet processed sections of the `ORIGINAL_TENSOR`.

---

**- step 3:** you are done, use the `RESULT_TENSOR` accumulated result, as it now holds all the Q-learning n-steps deep propagations of all non-zero values summed up with any cross-interfering side-effects avoided.